# How can I have carousel of basic cards in google actions app

Tags: chatbot, actions-on-google

I want to show a carousel with a list of  of basic cards (https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#basic_card) in google actions conversation response. I looked at the rich response(https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#rich-responses) and it allows only one basic card in it.

The reason I want to use basic card instead of carousel of option is simple. When I click on the carousel option it proceeds to next conversation, but with basic card I will be redirected to the external link, which is what I needed.

I'm using the code below to display a list of items(options) in carousel for a chat response currently. Any suggestions and help appreciated

```
        let carousel = app.buildCarousel()
        // carousel.addSimpleResponse();
        products_raw.forEach(function(item){
            console.log(item);
            carousel.addItems(
              app.buildOptionItem(item.title,)
              .setTitle(item.title)
              .setDescription(`Price: ${item.price}`)
              // .addButton('know more', item.url)
              .setImage(item.image, item.title)
              // .setImageDisplay('CROPPED')
            )
        });
        app.askWithCarousel(answerData.message_text, carousel)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a carrousel or list selector with multiple sites that you want to be able to choose from. Then when a user selects an item, build a basic card with the site you passed from the selector.

Comment: this sounds like a hack. is there no direct implementation what I wanted ?

Comment: There isn't. A Basic Card is the only way to link the user away from the conversation like that, so you'll have to work around the fact that it only allows 1 option. Technically I don't see the reason why a basic card is limited to 1 entry, so perhaps they'll allow a list like selector with a "read More" button in the future if someone addresses it.

Comment: Theres no technical reason, but there are some very good UX reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The two are intended to serve different purposes.

Carousel cards are meant to advance the conversation and provide visual information as part of advancing it. It isn't really meant to provide a final result or to produce something that takes you out of the conversation.

The basic card is meant as part of a result that supplements the voice part of the conversation. It can be the "end result" of a conversation, although it doesn't need to be. As such, it makes sense that it allow linking out to a website.

If you have a number of results as part of the conversation, it may be that there is more you need to do to advance the conversation along still.

Answer (score 0):

You can use browsing carousal for your use case, [Browsing Carousel](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#browsing_carousel)